# how to use multiple command in docker-compose cli

Tags: docker, docker-compose

developers

I need your help.
I want to use docker-compose command in cli like below.

```sh
docker-compose run --entrypoint="" my_app apt-get update && pip install -U pip
```

The reason why I use this is I want to use another command for test my container, cause there are my build command for django in my entrypoint.sh.

Can I use multiple command in cli environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute multiple commands use bash.
Example:

```
docker exec <container_name> bash "-c" "cd / && ls "
```